# How to use convolution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, transfer, convolution

My problem is find the output to `U(t+1)-U(t-1)` with Matlab given the transfer function `H(s)`.

I know that I should be able to find the output to any input of an LTI system when given `H(s)`, so I tried using convolution to find the output and plot it. Below is my attempt at using the `conv` to produce the output. `Ht= dirac(t) - 4*exp(-6*t)`

```
syms s t b
Hs=(s+2)/(s+6)
Ht=ilaplace(Hs)
tt=0:.1:60
Hnum= subs(Ht, 't',[eps:.1:10]);
%turn symbolic vector into actual
A=double(Hnum);
input=ones(1, 501);

output=conv(input,A)
figure(3)
plot(tt,output)
```

I also tried to use the integral way

```
 %b is tau 
 t1=0;
 t2=int(exp(-(6*b)),b,0,t+1)+1
 t3=int(exp(-(6*b)),b,t-1,t+1)
```

I know that `H(t)*x(t) = y(t)`.
I was not able to get any reasonable output for the graphs. Any hints or help are much appreciated.